# Async function never returns

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await, ecmascript-2017

I'm using Node version 7.6.0 to try out the native async and await features.

I'm trying to figure out why my async call just hanging never actually resolves.

NLP module:

```
const rest = require('unirest')
const Redis = require('ioredis')
const redis = new Redis()
const Promise = require('bluebird')
const nlp = {}
nlp.queryCache = function(text) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        redis.get(text, (err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log("Error querying Redis: ", err)
                reject(new Error("Error querying Redis: ", err))
            } else {
                if (result) {
                    let cache = JSON.parse(result)
                    console.log("Found cache in Redis: ", cache)
                    resolve(cache)
                } else {
                    resolve(null)
                }
            }
        })
    })
}

nlp.queryService = function(text) {
    console.log("Querying NLP Service...")
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        rest.get('http://localhost:9119?q=' + text)
            .end((response) => {
                redis.set(text, JSON.stringify(text))
                resolve(response.body)
            })
    })
}

nlp.query = async function(text) {
    try {
        console.log("LET'S TRY REDIS FIRST")
        let cache = await nlp.queryCache(text)
        if (cache) {
            return cache
        } else {
            let result = await nlp.queryService(text)
            console.log("Done Querying NLP service: ", result)
            return result
        }
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("Problem querying: ", e)
    }

}
module.exports = nlp
```

The module consumer:

```
const modeMenu = require('../ui/service_mode')
const nlp = require('../nlp')
const sess = require('../session')
const onGreetings = async function(req, res, next) {
    let state = sess.getState(req.from.id)
    if (state === 'GREET') {        
        let log = { 
            middleware: "onGreetings"           
        }
        console.log(log)
        let result = await nlp.query(req.text)
        console.log("XXXXXXXX: ", result)
        res.send({reply_id: req.from.id, message: msg})

    } else {
        console.log("This query is not not normal text from user, calling next()")
        next()
    }
};
module.exports = onGreetings;
```

I'm unable to get the code to proceed to following line:

```
console.log("XXXXXXXX: ", result)
```

I can see that the query was successful in the NLP module

[image: Console log output]

[Edit: Added console.log statement to response body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2T0GV.png)

[image: Console output on the actual response.body]

[image: Log statement]

Comment: Did you try to put an "async" on all functions that you try to "await" ? And so try to add "await" before "new Promise" too.

Comment: @Gilsdav - you don't `return await new Promise` - async/await is syntax sugar for Promises

Comment: which of the other `console.log` messages are displayed? Your logic seems sound

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for looking at this. As you can see @JaromandaX . I'm trying to query the NLP service only after I can't find the it in Redis.  The output from the nlp.query() call indicates that the call has returned successfully but it never passes it to the result variable.

Comment: put a `console.log(response.body)` inside `.end((response) => { ... }` - what does that show

Comment: I have updated with a couple more output results

Comment: Unless you just ran into a bug, there must be some piece of info missing. The only thing I can suggest is running your app with `node --inspect`, setting a breakpoint in your middleware, and stepping through the execution flow after it gets triggered (remember to check the Async option in the Chrome debugger).

Comment: You don't seem to be handling any errors from `rest.get`, in which case the promise would remain unresolved (and hang your `async function`) indefinitely.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The most likely cause is an error in a Promise that you aren't catching. I find it helps to avoid `try`-`catch` in all but the top calling method, and if a method can be `await`-ed it almost always should be.

In your case I think the problem is here:

```
nlp.queryService = function(text) {
    console.log("Querying NLP Service...")
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        rest.get('http://localhost:9119?q=' + text)
            .end((response) => {
                redis.set(text, JSON.stringify(text)) // this line is fire and forget
                resolve(response.body)
            })
    })
}
```

Specifically this line: `redis.set(text, JSON.stringify(text))` - that line is calling a function and nothing is catching any error.

The fix is to wrap all your Redis methods in promises, and then always `await` them:

```
nlp.setCache = function(key, value) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        redis.set(key, value, (err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(new Error("Error saving to Redis: ", err));
            } else {
                resolve(result);
            }
        });
    })
}

nlp.queryService = async function(text) {
    console.log("Querying NLP Service...")
    const p = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        rest.get('http://localhost:9119?q=' + text)
            .end((response) => { resolve(response.body) });

        // This is missing error handling - it should reject(new Error... 
        // for any connection errors or any non-20x response status 
    });

    const result = await p;

    // Now any issue saving to Redis will be passed to any try-catch
    await nlp.setCache(text, result);
    return;
}
```

As a general rule I find it's best practise to:

- Keep explicit promises low level - have `Promise` wrapper functions for your `rest` and `redis` callbacks.
- Make sure that your promises `reject` with `new Error` when something goes wrong. If a `Promise` doesn't `resolve` and doesn't `reject` then your code stops there.
- Every call to one of these promise wrappers should have `await`
- `try`-`catch` right at the top - as long as every `Promise` is `await`-ed any error thrown by any of them will end up in the top level `catch`

Most issues will either be:

- You have a `Promise` that can fail to `resolve` or `reject`.
- You call an `async function` or `Promise` without `await`.